# How to use a variable from php file to javascript file

Tags: javascript

How to use a variable from php file to javascript file

in php file I assigned the $phpVariable to jsVariable with this code:

```
<script> 
var jsVariable = <?php echo $phpVariable; ?>;
</script>
```

in Javascript file:   I test the jsVariable with this code:

```
<script>
alert( jsVariable );
</script>
```

but the output is ":undefined"

Thanks
Moi

Comment: Look in the browser console. If the variable's value is a string, you're missing quotes in the assignment.  There are lots and lots of very similar questions listed over there on the right side of the screen.

Comment: Do you have both the those script tags in the same PHP/html file? Also whats the value of `$phpVariable`? it needs to be quoted appropriately if its a string. Easiest way to take care of this is to use `echo json_encode($phpVariable)`

Answer (score 1):

If such variable is a string, you should wrap it in quotes:

```
<script> 
var jsVariable = "<?php echo $phpVariable; ?>";
</script>
```

EDIT but you should never do that. You'd better inject it as a `data-*` attribute of a DOM element, or either fetch it from a JSON config file / string you'll be parsing, like:

```
<script type="application/json" id="json-config">

<?php echo json_encode($someObject); ?>

</script>
```

And then:

```
var config = $.parseJSON( $('#json-config').html() )
```

Comment: This alone is not an XSS hole, only if you do not encode the `$phpVariable` before writing it into JS.

Comment: XSS is nonetheless a valid concern with this piece of code... so be sure to follow [these guidelines](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233_-_JavaScript_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_JavaScript_Data_Values) for encoding `$phpVariable` before wrtiting it to JS (if the value comes from user input)!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
print "<script>";
print "var jsVariable = $phpVariable"; 
print "</script>";
?>
```

Comment: This will work no better than the original if the value is a string.

Comment: For compatibility purposes across all php installations you should use `<?php` as your opening tag. The opening tag you used is referred to as a short tag and may not be allowed in all php installations as it is based on a setting in the `php.ini` file. Please ensure you write clean compatible code.

Comment: you are decreasing performance of server while you print constants values, so better way is use as moonwave99's example